# Error while using sudo command

Tags: mysql, linux, sudo

I was trying to install mysql on my Linux Mint 15, and I got the following error:

```
paul@paul-Ideapad-Z570 ~/un_test $ sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5
[sudo] password for paul: 
Sorry, user paul is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/apt-get install mysql-client-   core-5.5' as root on paul-Ideapad-Z570.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your user is in the /etc/sudoers file

First, log in as root or a user with root permissions

Use a text editor like Vim to open it up with

```
sudo vim /etc/sudoers
```

you will see a line like this in the file:

```
#Default rule for root.
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Insert your user under the root line to make it look like this

```
#Default rule for root.
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
youruser ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

save the file. After this, log in as your user and you can use sudo.

Comment: i am not 100% sure about linux mint, but hacking it like this is probably not recommended. if all commands should be permitted, there is probably a predefined group for this, maybe `adm` or something alike.

Comment: It is a quick and dirty way to give users full privileges, perhaps to just not use the user "root" for things like ssh security(disabling root login). If this is for other users that will be on your system, looking into group permissions is indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might be the answer to your problem
https://wiki.debian.org/sudo

Specifically the second sentence of the second paragraph. Follow the steps there and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

did you try doing `sudo -u [user with permission to install] apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5 ??`

I think the issue comes down to permissions of the user you are logged in as, you might have to sudo in as root or another user with permissions to do the install.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me

In the terminal enter as root like this

```js
su root
```

type your password below and then once you've logged in

```js
adduser <yourusername> sudo
```

Then you should be able to use sudo again

Hope it helps!